# SQL Merge tables and return oldest record

Tags: sql, oracle

What I'm trying to achieve is to merge two tables and return the oldest record, then join it to another table.

When I run the sub query on it's own it works ok, I know rows exist in the subquery. However, when I run it together, I get null in the column `First Seen` when joined to the main table. I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting null as the tag exists in table I and the tag exists in table FS.

```
SELECT  
    I.location_id, I.sku_id, I.description, I.qty_on_hand, 
    I.lock_status, I.tag_id, 
    NVL(i.condition_id, ' ') Condition,
    TO_CHAR(FS.dstamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "First Seen"
FROM 
    inventory I
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TAG_ID, dstamp 
     FROM
         (SELECT tag_id, dstamp 
          FROM inventory_transaction 
          WHERE code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')
          UNION
          SELECT tag_id, dstamp 
          FROM inventory_transaction_archive 
          WHERE code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')) itl
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1) FS ON I.TAG_ID = FS.TAG_ID
```

This is the result the above query returns:

[image]

Comment: your DBMS seems to be oracle, ain't it?

Comment: Yeah that's right, your query worked by the way. I'm going through the emotions of understanding exactly where i went wrong. I understand now! Thanks for your help Barbaros.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is sorting by `dtstamp` column within `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function in order to filter out the oldest records such as

```sql
WITH fs AS
(
 SELECT tag_id, dstamp,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag_id ORDER BY dstamp) AS rn
   FROM (SELECT tag_id, dstamp
           FROM inventory_transaction
          WHERE code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')
         UNION
         SELECT tag_id, dstamp
           FROM inventory_transaction_archive
          WHERE code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')) itl
)
SELECT I.location_id,
       I.sku_id,
       I.description,
       I.qty_on_hand,
       I.lock_status,
       I.tag_id,
       NVL(i.condition_id, ' ') Condition,
       TO_CHAR(FS.dstamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "First Seen"
  FROM inventory I
  LEFT JOIN fs 
    ON I.tag_id = fs.tag_id
   AND rn = 1
```

Comment: That is not a `LEFT JOIN` as the `WHERE` filter forces there to be a row and makes it an `INNER JOIN`. Either move the filter to the `ON` clause or also filter when `rn IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not work as:

1. `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` will find the first row and only return that; it does not find the first row for each `TAG_ID`.
2. Even if it did work, which it doesn't, it would still return incorrect results as you are not using an `ORDER BY` clause so the rows will be numbered in the (pseudo-random) order they are processed by the SQL engine and not in any particular date order.

In Oracle 12 and later, you can use a `LATERAL` join and use an `ORDER BY` clause in the sub-query and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` (and since you only want a single row, you can also use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`):

```sql
SELECT I.location_id,
       I.sku_id,
       I.description,
       I.qty_on_hand, 
       I.lock_status,
       I.tag_id, 
       NVL(i.condition_id, ' ') Condition,
       TO_CHAR(FS.dstamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "First Seen"
FROM   inventory I
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT tag_id,
                dstamp 
         FROM   inventory_transaction it
         WHERE  code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')
         AND    it.TAG_ID = i.TAG_ID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT tag_id,
                dstamp 
         FROM   inventory_transaction_archive ita
         WHERE  code IN ('Receipt', 'Stock Check')
         AND    ita.TAG_ID = i.TAG_ID
         ORDER BY dstamp
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) fs
       ON (1=1)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=827a6158f256977bd0a0df2a412cd1c2)*

Answer (score 0):

ROWNUM = 1 is wrong condition because ROWNUM get only one row, well only one TAG_ID.
try this SQL.

```
SELECT  I.location_id, I.sku_id, I.description, I.qty_on_hand, I.lock_status, I.tag_id, 
     nvl(i.condition_id,' ') Condition,
     to_char(FS.dstamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "First Seen"
     FROM inventory I
      LEFT JOIN 
               (SELECT itl.TAG_ID, MIN(dstamp) dstamp FROM
                 (SELECT tag_id, dstamp FROM inventory_transaction WHERE code IN ('Receipt','Stock 
                  Check')
                  union
                  SELECT tag_id, dstamp FROM inventory_transaction_archive WHERE code IN 
                  ('Receipt','Stock Check'))itl
                  GROUP BY itl.TAG_ID ) 
                  FS  
      ON I.TAG_ID = FS.TAG_ID
```